# Is it possible to search in a list that has string and intergers

Tags: python, search

for instance, if the input was 6 it would search for the string six how could I change that it to an int

```
def test_search(li, item):

    i = 0
    while i < len(li):
        if item == li[i]:
            return i
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return -1

items = input('what item are  you looking for? ')

lis = ['he', 'she', 6, 2]
print(test_search(lis, items))
```

Comment: Did you try running it? What happened?  Does your code not produce the expected results? If not, show the input given and the expected output and then show the input given and the _actually_ output/error you are getting.

Comment: `if item == str(li[i]):` will be the simplest modification to make it work

Comment: @abccd Note that would only work if the OP didn't want a distinction between types. Nevertheless, it is the easiest and quickest fix.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` in Python returns a string. Because of this, `item` will be equal to `"6"` rather than the integer `6`. This means `item` will never be found in `lis` because `"6" != 6`. You need someway to know when to convert your user input to an integer, and when to leave it as a string.

One approach you could take is to ask the user whether they are searching for an integer or a string, and convert the input accordingly:

```
item = input('')
item_type = input('')

# The default item type will be string. If the user wants to change
# this they can enter "int" for integers.
if item_type == 'int':
    item = int(item)

lis = ['he', 'she', 6, 2]
print(test_search(lis, item))
```

For the inputs `6` and `int`, the above code outputs:

```
6
```

As [@abccd mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135483/is-it-possible-to-search-in-a-list-that-has-string-and-intergers#comment77240461_45135483), if the type of your elements do not matter, you can simply convert all elements of your list to one type - strings:

```
...
while i < len(li):
    if item == str(li[i]):
        return i
...
```

On an unrelated side note to the problem, your `search` function can be implemented much cleaner by using `for` rather than `while`:

```
def search(item, lst):
    """
    search for `item` in `lst`. If `item` is found, return
    `item`, otherwise return `-1`.
    """
    for element in lst:
        if item == element:
            return item
    return -1
```